# calculating the daily rewards for liquidity provider in Uniswap

Tags: solidity, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I am integrating the Uniswap contracts and want to understand how could I calculate the daily rewards for the liquidity provider.
I understand that I could get the `pairAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender)` for each day and subtract the numbers from each other, but it doesn't seem the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this regarding V3 or V2? In either, LP rewards do not accrue directly to a LP token holder. In V2 they are reinvested into the pool, and in V3 they are collected separately and must be redeemed by calling the pool contract directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is regarding V2, but I still don't understand, where the user could see how much did he earn since the beginning. (or at least how much liquidity does he/she earns currently).